# How to benchmark asp.net core REST APIs using BenchmarkDotNet?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, benchmarkdotnet

I do have an existing rest API project developed using asp.net core 3.1. At present, we are planning to do code refactoring and optimize it.
 I came across [BenchMarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org) recently. 
All the examples that I have come across are mostly targeted for console-based applications. 
I wanted to leverage this in the case of REST API project too, but did not come across any reference examples in context to its usage.

**Code:**

```
[Route("api/[Action]")]
[ApiController]
[AllowModule(AppType = ApplicationType.Testing)]
public class TestController : BaseController
{
    private readonly ITestService _testService;
    public TestController(ITestService testService, ILogger<TestController> logger) : base(logger)
    {
        _testService = testService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(testService));
    }

    [HttpGet("{inspectionID:long}", Name = "GetDetails")]
    [ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "Never")]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    [ProducesResponseType(500)]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TestDTO>> Get(long inspectionID) => await _testService.GetDetails(inspectionID);
}
```

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance?

Comment: Can you post a sample endpoint from one of your controllers? There are multiple ways to benchmark, and the "best" way may vary based on your implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Luke for your response. I have added the endpoint. Any help on this request is much appreciated

Comment: So you have a choice here: do you want to 1) benchmark end-to-end REST response times (understanding that it's not representative of what actual clients will experience, due to networking delay variances) OR 2) benchmark your `TestService.GetDetails` method (and other methods)?

Comment: Option 2: TestService.GetDetails looks to be good in this case

Comment: @Luke In this case TestService class is DI enabled. Can you please guide me how to benchmark DI enabled class. Any help on this request is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think `BenchmarkDotNet` is not the right tool for the task.
BenchmarkDotNet measures the performance inside the process that it is within. 
It will not measure the performance of another process (ASP.NET application in this case)
There are other tools that benchmark API like [crank](https://github.com/dotnet/crank). 
This tool is from Microsoft.
Here is [a video from Microsoft Conf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IgfrnG-128)  to explain how to work with it.